# What is the diferrence between webmasters and webapps?

Tags: discussion

What is the diferrence between webmasters.stackexchange and webapps.stackexchange?

Thanks

Comment: This should be on meta.

Answer (score 9):

Had a look at the FAQ's for both pages and it seems that webapps is more for **users of web applications** while webmasters is for **those who operate websites**.

**Webapps** https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq

What kind of questions can I ask here?

Web Apps - Stack Exchange is for expert and advanced users of web applications. If your question generally covers …

1. Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
2. Bookmarklets
3. Browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc)

**Webmasters** https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq

What kind of questions can I ask here?

Pro Webmasters - Stack Exchange is for professional and enthusiast webmasters. If your question generally covers the operation of websites which you control, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!